# How to create EditText in Java Code for Android?

Tags: android

I made my first application for Android using only Java code. How do I create an EditText in Java Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have formatted it in XML:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/edittextid"
     android:inputType="text" >
```

You can call it by declaring it and linking it to the view you specified in the XML like so:

```
EditText et = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edittextid);
```

You can get more info on the class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

Answer (score 2):

Is more or less works like this:

```
EditText et = new EditTex(context);
```

where the `context` is e.g. the `Activity` that hosts the `EditText`.
In practice you may want to do some customizing and then attach it to an existing layout like e.g.

```
EditText et = new EditText(getActivity());
et.setTextAppearance(getActivity(),R.style.table_cell); // add some style
et.setTag(name);  // add a tag

if(PropertyType.isNumeric(spd.getType())) {
     et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL); // Input are numbers only
}

if (spd.getDefaultValue()!=null) {
        et.setText(""+spd.getDefaultValue()); // set a default text to be displayed
}
row.addView(et); // add it to a parent
```

Comment: hey i have a question, i declare context just like this:
  private Context context;
 EditText et = new EditText(context);

its correct?

Comment: The context needs to be set by someone (e.g. getActivity() as in my longer example (which was from within a Fragment), via using the current activity as context ('this') or via `getApplicationContext()`. Activity inherits from Context. So whenever you a Context is needed and you have an Activity around, you can use the activity for this.

Comment: How to add a LeftDrawable on this ediText